# Вывод текста glfw3 c++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw

Пишу программу при помощи glfw, необходимо вывести текст в окне. Как это можно сделать???
Насколько я понял, можно вывести текст при помощи glut, но, в таком случае, возникает вопрос: могут ли glfw и glut работать с одним и тем же окном? Если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

> могут ли glfw и glut работать с одним и тем же окном

Вряд ли. Да и GLUT - старая библиотека, не надо брать ее только потому, что там просто рисовать текст.

Текст можно рисовать и в голом OpenGL. Делаете или находите текстуру со всеми нужными символами, потом рисуете текст из отдельных прямоугольничков (1 на символ).

Вот тут есть хороший туториал: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering

Варианты:

- Можно использовать [libfreetype](https://www.freetype.org) чтобы на ходу создавать текстуры из векторных шрифтов.
- Можно подготавливать текстуру заранее с помощью чего-то вроде [bmfont](https://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/).
- Можно найти или нарисовать шрифт сразу в виде картинки.